# %cd transformed to Í in ajax to php call

Tags: php, jquery, char

I have this weird issue which i'm absolutely don't even know how to address...

i have this little AJAX call:

```
    $('#toexcel').live("click",function() {
        var sql = grid.data().sql;
        $.ajax({
            url: "toExcel.php",
            data: "sql="+sql,
            success: function(response){
                window.location.href = response.url;
            }
        });
        alert(sql);
    });
});
```

which passes `sql` query from `grid` object to `toExcel`. `toExcel` uses `PHPExcel` object to output excel file.

now:

when alert pops up it has normally looking query `...LIKE '%cdviled%'...`

but when i access this query in toExcel.php it looks like `...LIKE 'Íviled04%'....`
 and query obviously fails.

why????? how??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%cd` is a valid URL-encoded representation of `Í` and PHP handles it as such.

The solution is simple. Change:

```
data: "sql="+sql,
```

to:

```
data: "sql="+encodeURIComponent(sql),
```

Comment: it's strange i have never came across this issue before. i googled %cd but it didn't bring up any relevant info, then again search engines don't like special chars such as % =)

Comment: @Elen What might have given you a clue is if you had Googled `Í` and looked at the URL it produces... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

PHP is interpreting `%cd` as a [URL-encoded entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  You will want to run your parameters through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before sending off the ajax request.

Although, you might get better (and more secure) results by simply sending the search term via ajax and letting PHP assemble the SQL on the server side!

Comment: @DaveRandom You get a +1 from me, too for providing an example (:

Comment: Thanks Phoenix for being first and explanation, but i will accept Dave's answer purely because he appreciated my laziness by providing working code straight away =)) +1 from me